# Adjusting the header on the second page of my TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I've defined my table of contents, list of equations, list of figures and list of tables.
My list of tables is now on the second page of the contents, but then a header appears, which I want gone. But I can't seem to find the solution.

I've tried to adjust my pagestyle of the TOC/LOF/LOT also in the document as the headers itself. So anyone got a clue how to fix this? I've circled it in red what I want to remove.
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}    
\usepackage{titleps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{titleps,lipsum}
    \newpagestyle{nice}{
      \setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
      \sethead[Thesis]% even left
        []% even centre
        [\thechapter. \chaptertitle]% even right
        {\thechapter. \chaptertitle}% odd left
        {}% odd centre
        {Thesis}% odd right
      
      \setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}
    }
    \newpagestyle{introduction}{
      \setheadrule{.0pt}% Header rule
      \sethead[]% even left
        []% even centre
        []% even right
        {}% odd left
        {}% odd centre
        {}% odd right
      
      \setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}
    }
  
    \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}
    
    \definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
    \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
    % \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\vspace{-2cm}\huge\bfseries}{\vspace{-1.250in}\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\huge\bfseries}[\vspace{-1.0cm}]
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\vspace{-2cm}\huge}{\vspace{-1.250in}\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\huge}[\vspace{-1.0cm}]
    \titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont \Large}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\slshape \large}
    
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \newcommand{\listequationsname}{\thispagestyle{introduction}\normalfont{\huge{List of Equations}}}
    \newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
    \newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
    \setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}% Width of equation number in List of Equations
    \setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}% indent of equation number in List of Equations
    
    \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\newpage\huge} %adjusting size TOC
    \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\huge\pagestyle{plain}} %adjusting size lof
    \renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\huge\pagestyle{plain}} %adjusting size lot
    
    
    
    \makeglossaries
    \input{glossaries}
    \begin{document}
        \input{Frontpage/Frontpage_new}
        \input{Frontpage/Preface}
        \input{Frontpage/Summary}
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
        
        \tableofcontents
        \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
        \listofmyequations
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables

    \pagestyle{nice}
    \input{Chapters/01Introduction}
    \input{Chapters/02TheoreticalFramwork}
    \input{Chapters/03Methodology}
    \input{Chapters/04Results}
    \input{Chapters/05Conclusion}
    \input{Chapters/06Recommendation}
    
    
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
    \printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see that you have defined `\newpagestyle{introduction}{...}`. Have you tried to put `\pagestyle{introduction}` before `\tableofcontents` ?

Comment: I've done that. But it doesn't make a difference. I've got a \newpage in the \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\newpage\huge} to prevent it from being on the same page as my summary. But if I leave the \newpage out I dont have the issue anymore

Comment: What about `\newpage` before `\pagestyle{nice}` ?

Comment: Thanks that's it! I Was struggling for hours with this issue

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...